# K8s manual ingress controller config

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm running a bare metal k8s cluster so I have to configure ingress-nginx manually.
I have applied the mandatory yaml and bare-metal yaml:
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml

As described in the [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md#bare-metal).
I am not sure if I need to apply anything else, like RBAC. This created a deployment, and a pod but no service. I need to create the service, using the NodePort method described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/baremetal.md).

The problem is my service is not starting, it stays in pending. Did anyone have any success with this? How does the nginx service need to be configured?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with pending state on bare metal may be caused:

- Your service can't receive  IP address from external.
- Your service can't claim the port on system because it is already in use.

In you case, it looks like your service can't claim the port. Could you try to use different ports on the system (for testing at the beginning):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      nodePort: 30080
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      nodePort: 30443
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

and then your ingress will available to those nodePorts   `30236 -> 80` and `30443 -> 443` from external.

Comment: Will 80 and 443 be the ones accessed from the exterior? Because i am a bit confused on how all this works at the moment. I already have a nodePort service for my app, so i can actually access it on hostname:32448 at the moment. The issue is that i have 2 nodes and i understand that these 30000 ports can change. So i want to be able to access my app from outside on 80. Then if either ingress can take care of the load balancing, that's fine, or i can setup an F5, that's also fine. But if the ports change it should work automatically with the new ports.

Comment: In case when you define port in service it will doesn't change until you change it. In same time you need to make some some load balancer (Nginx HAproxy) under your kubernetes cluster. Usually when it is cloud cloud provider make it for you. But when you use bare metal you need to configure all by yourself.

Comment: Well, my service is defined with 32448. If it doesn't change then I can just make an lb farm on my F5 with port translation on the virtual server until I figure out the k8s stuff.